# getParameter returns null with Fetch API

Tags: javascript, java, fetch

My problem is that `request.getParameter("username")` returns **null** if I use the Fetch API. Without the Fetch API it works fine and returns the value.

```
document.getElementById('login').addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    fetch('login', {
        method: 'POST'
    })
    .then((response) => {
        return response.text();
    })
    .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
    })
});
```

What is missing?

This is how I try to catch the value:

```
@WebServlet("/login")
public class Login extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
        System.out.println(req.getParameter("username"));
    }
}
```

`username` = `<input id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" type="text">`

Comment: [Java != JavaScript](http://javascriptisnotjava.com)

Comment: @JackBashford `request.getParameter("username")` is Java!

Comment: I'm not sure where `request.getParameter("username")` comes in, but I would guess this is from the server-side code that processes this Ajax request. And I can't help but note that you are sending no data (and therefore in particular no `username` field) with the request in the code above...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I already noted in the comments, you're not actually sending any data with your Ajax call - so it is no wonder that the server cannot see any `username` property.

All you should need to do to have this work as intended is to replace this:

```
fetch('login', {
    method: 'POST'
})
```

with

```
fetch('login', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: {username: document.getElementById("username").value}
})
```

This is assuming the username you want to send is the value the user has entered in the "username" input (which I feel is a reasonable assumption). Any other data you want to send with the request should be added as further key-value pairs in the `body` parameter of the options object you supply to `fetch`.

Comment: Thank you, that was what I've been looking for!